# WinRT C#: Cannot save UnhandledException to Storage

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'm working on WinRT. If an unhandled exception is thrown I want to write the message text to the storage. 
I added an Event handler in 'App.xaml.cs', see the code.

The exception is caught but the last line, where the file is written, crashes again -> 'exception'!

Why? Any idea?

```
 public App()
 {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
 }

 async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
 {
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; 
    StorageFile file= await folder.CreateFileAsync("crash.log",CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, e.Message);  // <----- crash again -----
 }
```

Thanks

Sunny

Comment: I repro.  Pretty hard to diagnose, the AppendTextAsync() call fails in a very nasty way.  You'd better avoid using *await* in this code, I guess.

Comment: you think a deferral might be needed here?

Answer (score 4):

I've been wondering the same thing and stumbled across this quite early on in my search. I've figured out a way, hopefully this will prove useful to someone else too.

The problem is that `await` is returning control of the UI thread and the app's crashing. You need a deferral but there's no real way to get one.

My solution is to use the settings storage, instead. I'm assuming most people wanting to do this want to do something LittleWatson style, so here's some code modified from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx for your convenience:

```
namespace YourApp
{
    using Windows.Storage;
    using Windows.UI.Popups;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class LittleWatson
    {
        private const string settingname = "LittleWatsonDetails";
        private const string email = "mailto:?to=you@example.com&subject=YourApp auto-generated problem report&body=";
        private const string extra = "extra", message = "message", stacktrace = "stacktrace";

        internal static void ReportException(Exception ex, string extraData)
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer(settingname, Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
            var exceptionValues = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Containers[settingname].Values;

            exceptionValues[extra] = extraData;
            exceptionValues[message] = ex.Message;
            exceptionValues[stacktrace] = ex.StackTrace;
        }

        internal async static Task CheckForPreviousException()
        {
            var container = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Containers;
            try
            {
                var exceptionValues = container[settingname].Values;
                string extraData = exceptionValues[extra] as string;
                string messageData = exceptionValues[message] as string;
                string stacktraceData = exceptionValues[stacktrace] as string;

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine(extraData);
                sb.AppendLine(messageData);
                sb.AppendLine(stacktraceData);

                string contents = sb.ToString();

                SafeDeleteLog();

                if (stacktraceData != null && stacktraceData.Length > 0)
                {
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog("A problem occured the last time you ran this application. Would you like to report it so that we can fix the error?", "Error Report")
                    {
                        CancelCommandIndex = 1,
                        DefaultCommandIndex = 0
                    };

                    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Send", async delegate
                    {
                        var mailToSend = email.ToString();
                        mailToSend += contents;
                        var mailto = new Uri(mailToSend);
                        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
                    }));
                    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel"));

                    await dialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                // KeyNotFoundException will fire if we've not ever had crash data. No worries!
            }
        }

        private static void SafeDeleteLog()
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer(settingname, Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
            var exceptionValues = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Containers[settingname].Values;

            exceptionValues[extra] = string.Empty;
            exceptionValues[message] = string.Empty;
            exceptionValues[stacktrace] = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

To implement it, you need to do the same as the link above says, but to ensure the data's here in case the url ever goes down:

`App.xaml.cs` Constructor (BEFORE the call to `this.InitializeComponent()`):

```
this.UnhandledException += (s, e) => LittleWatson.ReportException(e.Exception, "extra message goes here");
```

Obviously if you already have an UnhandledException method you can throw the call to LittleWatson in there.

If you're on Windows 8.1, you can add a NavigationFailed call too. This needs to be in an actual page (typically MainPage.xaml.cs or whatever page is first opened):

`xx.xaml.cs` Constructor (any given page):

```
rootFrame.NavigationFailed += (s, e) => LittleWatson.ReportException(e.Exception, "extra message goes here");
```

Lastly, you need to ask the user if they want to send the e-mail when the app re-opens. In your app's default Page's constructor (default: the page App.xaml.cs initializes):

```
this.Loaded += async (s, e) => await LittleWatson.CheckForPreviousException();
```

Or add the call to your OnLoad method if you already use it.

Comment: Do you know if this applies to Windows 8 AND 8.1 apps?

Comment: I can't confirm it because I don't have a Windows 8.0 machine lying around, nor VS 2012. I've opened an old 8.0 app though, and the LittleWatson code itself works fine. However, 8.0 seems to not have the "NavigationFailed" event, so you'll only be able to have the UnhandledException event calling LittleWatson in App.xaml.cs - the rootFrame bit won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, `await` could be loosely translated to "do this job on another thread, and continue what you were doing while you wait for it to finish". Given that what your app was doing was *crashing*, you probably don't want it to continue doing that until you're done logging the problem. I'd suggest running your file IO synchronously in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This may come a bit too late for the original question but...

as @Hans Passant suggested, avoiding `await` (i.e., running the `FileIO.AppendTextAsync()` synchronously), also seconded by @Jon, I would opt for this rather than the relatively too heavy code for *LittleWatson*. As the app is in some error handing state anyway (this should be a rare occurrence) I wouldn't put any blocking arising from synchronous (due to removing await) as a major downside.

Leaving the synchronous option to one side, the following `await` implementation worked for me:

Change `await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, e.Message);` to:

```
Task task = LogErrorMessage(file, e.Message)
task.Wait(2000); // adjust the ms value as appropriate
```

...

```
private async Task LogErrorMessage(StorageFile file, string errorMessage)
{
    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, errorMessage); // this shouldn't crash in App_UnhandledException as it did before
}
```